# Sequential scan over index scan used on truncated DATE field

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I use PostgreSQL and I have a table called `table`.
This table contains a column called `created_at` (`data_type` is `timestamptz`) which is indexed using BTREE.

I would like to count the number of rows grouped by `created_at::date` over a period of time (filter by `from_date` and `end_date`).

I run the following query (the result is as expected):

```sql
SELECT ("table"."created_at" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date AS "date",
       COUNT("table"."id") AS "count"
FROM "table"
WHERE ("table"."created_at" >= '2018-08-05T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz AND "table"."created_at" <= '2020-09-05T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz)
GROUP BY ("table"."created_at" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date
ORDER BY "date" ASC
```

This query takes a long time to run (over 2 million rows) and when looking at the Query Plan, I noticed that there is a heavy **Seq Scan**:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=538741.06..605206.42 rows=2954016 width=12) (actual time=3866.460..5077.054 rows=559 loops=1)
  Group Key: ((timezone('UTC'::text, created_at))::date)
  ->  Sort  (cost=538741.06..546126.10 rows=2954016 width=8) (actual time=3866.414..4413.922 rows=2954016 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ((timezone('UTC'::text, created_at))::date)
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 52056kB
        ->  Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..140489.32 rows=2954016 width=8) (actual time=0.070..2194.108 rows=2954016 loops=1)
              Filter: ((created_at >= '2018-08-05 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= '2020-09-05 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
Planning time: 1.018 ms
Execution time: 5094.280 ms
```

I would like to understand the following:

1. What should be improved in the query (if any)
2. What should be improved in the table structure (if any)
3. Is the index type used (BTREE) appropriate for such queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your WHERE condition doesn't actually filter out any rows, so all rows from the table are processed. In that case, using a Seq Scan is the most efficient way to retrieve the data. If you make the time range smaller so that only a small percent of the table's rows are retrieved the optimizer should use the index.

The Seq Scan takes only half of the query time, the other half is spent in the GROUP BY (or the sorting for it). If you increase `work_mem` at least the sorting/grouping  should be faster (with more `work_mem`) the sorting is likely to be replaced with a hash aggregate.

Assuming `id` is defined as `not null`, then using `count(*)` instead of `count(id)` would also make the query faster. For one because the "null check" is no longer needed in the count function. But more importantly because Postgres is likely to an Index Only Scan as only the `created_at` column is needed which is available directly in the index. If this doesn't switch to an Index Only Scan, you might wan to run `vacuum analyze the_table;` to update the visibility map.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name for the clear explanation. For the first point, yes, you are right. For the GROUP BY, I will try the `work_mem` increase and adjust. The last point is also helpful (less impact).